# Ki'bolo Kach Polto

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, water, kashering-kosherization

Why can't a utensil that became trief at, say 150 degrees be kashered with water that is 151 degrees? Why must the water be boiling?

Comment: How do you know it must be?

Comment: This need a better title. Also I thought it was כבלעו not כדי לבלעו

Comment: Supra liminal heat is perhaps the principle

Comment: I think the "as absorbs, so emits" is a categorical halacha. So there would be temperature levels like "Yad Soledet Bo" and "Boiling", rather than continuous values. There's still the question of why you have to go up a level in temperature (Boiling rather than Yad Soledet Bo)

Answer (score 5):

R Ezra Friedman from OU Kashrut brings an answer to your question ([here](https://assets.torahtidbits.com/2021/01/27104207/1405-Beshalach-Rabbi-Friedman.pdf))

> It would seem logical based on the principle of kebol’o kach polto
> that not only would the method of kashering be based on the form of
> absorption but the temperature as well. For example, if a utensil
> absorbed non-kosher soup at low heat, one might assume that the hot
> water used in the kashering process to remove the absorbed flavor
> would only need to be slightly hotter than the temperature that the
> soup was cooked at. However, it is clear from early authorities (see
> Rabeinu Yona Hagalat Keilim 40) and codified in the Shulchan Aruch and
> Rema ([OH 452:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.452.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) that this is not the case. In order to remove absorbed
> flavor from the utensil, the water must be boiling hot, even if the
> original absorption occurred at a lower temperature.
>
> This concept is explained by Rav Aharon Pfeuffer in his book Kitzur
> Shulchan Aruch Basar Bechalav (volume 2 appendix:1). **When our Sages
> codified the rule of kebol’o kach polto, it related to the form of
> absorption such as water or fire and not the temperature needed to
> remove the flavor. In order to remove absorbed flavor, a higher
> temperature is needed than the temperature in which the food was
> cooked. The temperature of the water must be boiling in order to
> remove all of the flavor.** It should be noted, however, that Rav Moshe
> Feinstein (Igrot Moshe YD 4:36) and other poskim ruled that in
> situations of severe need, hag’alah may be done using water only
> slightly hotter than the temperature at which the food was absorbed.
> The OU does not rely on this leniency.

Comment: The Shulchan Aruch and Rama are in siman 452, not 552.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the correction